# Query select field on JqGrid edit form

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have this column Model on JqGrid:

```
{name:'ta',index:'ta',jsonmap:'ta',width:70,editable:true,edittype:'select',
editoptions: {dataUrl:hostname+'/sisfa/ta_cb'}}
```

I am using JqGrid form editing to edit this field. How to 'catch' the field editor for this field on form editing. I'm using this method, but not work

```
.editGridRow("new", 
        {closeAfterAdd: true, addCaption:'Add Data',
        width:500,dataheight:300,beforeShowForm:function(formid){
            console.log($('#tr_ta').find('select[name=ta]'));
        }});
```

This method work for other edittype.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code from [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) to `dataInit` of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions). In the case you will be sure that the code will be executed *after* the `<select>` will be created and filled with the data received from the server.